# Overloading structs with template call operator and generic lambdas - gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, lambda, overloading, language-lawyer, c++17

I have discovered a code snippet that compiles and works properly in **clang++ 4 (and trunk)** but fails to compile in **g++ 7 (and trunk)**. Let's assume I have the following `struct` types:

```
struct a { void foo() { } };
struct b { void bar() { } };
struct c { void bar() { } };
```

I want to create an *overload set* out of lambdas which handles `a` explicitly, while `b` and `c` are "caught" with a generic lambda using an `auto` parameter:

```
auto ol = overload([](a x)   { x.foo(); },
                   [](auto x){ x.bar(); })
```

When I invoke `ol(a{})`:

- **clang++** compiles and behaves as expected: `a` "matches" the first lambda, while `b` and `c` match the second one.
- **g++** fails to compile, with the following error:

  ```
  error: 'struct a' has no member named 'bar'
             [](auto x){ x.bar(); };
                         ~~^~~
  ```

  It seems that the compiler tries to instantiate the second lambda even though the first one is a way better match. Hopefully this is a bug, as it seems unintuitive to me.

---

Note both compilers work properly if instead of *lambda expressions* I use some old-fashioned `struct` instances:

```
struct s0
{
    auto operator()(a x) const { x.foo(); }
};

struct s1
{
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(T x) const { x.bar(); }
};

auto os = overload(s0{}, s1{});
os(a{}); // OK!
```

I would expect the lambdas to be roughly equivalent to `s0` and `s1`, so this is even more surprising.

---

This is the way I'm producing the overload set:

```
template <typename... Fs>
struct overloader : Fs...
{
    template <typename... FFwds>
    overloader(FFwds&&... fs) : Fs{std::forward<FFwds>(fs)}...
    {
    }

    using Fs::operator()...;
};

template <typename... Fs>
auto overload(Fs&&... fs)
{
    return overloader<std::decay_t<Fs>...>{std::forward<Fs>(fs)...};
}
```

And here's a [**live example on `gcc.godbolt.org`**](https://godbolt.org/g/maHfcb), showing the different behavior between the compilers.

---

**Is this a g++ bug?** Or is there something in the standard that makes lambdas behave differently from `struct` instances in this situation?

Comment: Huh, when did `using <> ...` enter the standard? C++17?

Comment: @NirFriedman Yep, in C++17, thanks to [P0195](http://wg21.link/p0195)

Comment: Aside: being able to take function pointers as argument to `overload` is nice.  To do this, replace `: Fs...` with `: some_magic<Fs>...`, where `some_magic` detects function pointers and maps it to a class storing it, and everything else it leaves alone.  (But maybe this overload is a simplified MCVE, in which case ignore this)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a gcc bug (submitted as [80767](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80767)), running afoul of [[temp.inst]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#9):

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement, unless such instantiation is required.

The instantiation of the generic lambda's `operator()` with `auto = a` is not required, hence it should not be instantiated.

Comment: The error comes from instantiating the conversion function template to pointer-to-function, meaning that this is another version of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71117.